# Problem with usb driver: ti_usb_3410_5052

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, drivers

I have problems with my USB driver. After adding my device (MSP430 USB-DEBUG-INTERFACE) it doesn't work.

```
[   60.476039] usb 2-2.1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 8
[   60.693959] ti_usb_3410_5052 2-2.1:1.0: TI USB 3410 1 port adapter converter detected
[   60.693981] ti_usb_3410_5052: probe of 2-2.1:1.0 failed with error -5
```

I try to do:

```
modprobe ti_usb_3410_5052
```

No changes.

It's Linux

```
Linux ubuntu 2.6.35-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 17:40:44 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I believe you need to check out the sources and look into probe function to see what the hell -5 actually means.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you faced a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/236247) when firmware file is expected to have a new name.
This should help:

```
sudo cp /lib/firmware/$(uname -r)/ti_3410.fw /lib/firmware/ti_usb-3410.bin
```

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Please provide full log.